# assign data list to spinner from Web-service in android

Tags: android, database, web-services, spinner

I am getting data from database through web-service. I have to set the data to spinner. Is it possible to assign data to spinner from DB? If possible how it is? Please help me.
thanks in advance........

Comment: <spinMobilePlatform=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinMobilePlatform);
 mobileAdapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.mobileplatform_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
 mobileAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
 spinMobilePlatform.setAdapter(mobileAdapter);>

Comment: what to be change in above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes** you it is you can read data from db and then set to spinner.

see [this example](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/2012/09/android-populate-spinner-from-sqlite.html)